# Data table takes more time to load while calling second time without reloading in client side

Tags: jquery, datatables

Data table takes more time to load while calling second time without reloading the page. If i reload datatable is cleared so it is fast but without reloading takes more time in client side

Comment: Why on earth was this upvoted? It's a poor quality question. You'll have to post some code or explain the problem more clearly - what do you mean 'calling second time without reloading the page'? is this paging or filtering the datatable?

Comment: Please specify your question, what is your problem?

Comment: Agree with @markpsmith - please include the code in the question as well.

Comment: function configtable(tbl) {
            oTable = $(tbl).dataTable({
                'bDestroy': true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": 'RCT<"clear">lfrtip'
        }

Comment: used on click event to call this fuction.i'll load different values retured from database into datatable when each time clicked.i have found that first time datatable is empty so it takes 5 second  to load 10000 records from second time takes 10 to 15 secs to load same 10000 records.

Comment: All i have done in client side using jquery.I think i tried to explain what's my problem as much i can --@ markpsmith, @Philip G, @ davidkonrad